# How to do desktop application for Windows with Ironpython?

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ironpython, windows

i'm starting to learn programmig in python, i have programmed in java, android, web, c++.

Now i want do desktop aplication with Visual Studio 2015 using IronPython for IronPython WPF Application, but i dont know if it's a good idea or it's better do it with Visual c# or Visual c++ because there are more information about this.

i pref do it with IronPython but i need information, and i need examples of a standar structure of a application desktop for windows because i want do a simple application but do it fine.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/winforms/) may be able to provide some insight in how to use Windows forms in your IronPython application.

If you plan on making an executable file, pyc.py located in the IronPython directory can be used.

Comment: well i want do it like Ironpypthon WPF Application Windows and use XAML and in examples like that dont use it :( they dont show how do reference to XAML objects created